# For a blurred UIVibrancyEffect to work, do we have to add it as a separate view to a UIBlurEffect's contentView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, swift, ios8

I'm trying to use `UIVibrancyEffect` to add a blurred vibrant overlay similar to Control Center in iOS 7/8. I tried just creating a `UIVisualEffectView` with the `UIVibrancyEffect` then adding that to my view, but the result isn't blurred, just made vibrant.

In order to get it to blur it seems I have to add the vibrant effect view to the content view of a blur effect view:

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];

UIVisualEffectView *effectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
effectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

// Add the blur effect to an image view.
[self.imageView addSubview:effectView];

[self.imageView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[v]|" options:0 metrics:nil views: @{ @"v" : effectView }]];
[self.imageView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[v]|" options:0 metrics:nil views: @{ @"v" : effectView }]];

UIVibrancyEffect *vibrance = [UIVibrancyEffect effectForBlurEffect:blurEffect];
UIVisualEffectView *effectView2 = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:vibrance];
effectView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

// Add the vibrance effect to our blur effect view 
[effectView.contentView addSubview:effectView2];

[effectView.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[v]|" options:0 metrics:nil views: @{ @"v" : effectView2 }]];
[effectView.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[v]|" options:0 metrics:nil views: @{ @"v" : effectView2 }]];

self.test = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.test.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.test.text = @"TEST";
self.test.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.test.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:30];
self.test.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

// Add label to the vibrance content view.
[effectView2.contentView addSubview:self.test];
[effectView2.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.test attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:effectView2.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[effectView2.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.test attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:effectView2.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

([Credit to Justin Williams](https://gist.github.com/justin/6914d5a5829079371e2e))

Is this the case? If so, why do I have to pass the blur effect when instantiating the `UIVibrancyEffect`? Are we able to have unblurred vibrant views? If so I can't seem to get that working, nor do I see why you're passing a blur.

Comment: You may think that you are specifying the `UIBlurEffect` twice but - `UIVibrancyEffect` takes the `UIBlurEffect` in it's initializer to let it know how to create that specific vibrancy effect for the blur you plan to use. You can always just pass the `UIVisualEffectView` `effect` property to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the questions in your last paragraph in order: Yes; because that's what it's for; no.

The sole purpose of a vibrancy effect is to act in harmony with an underlying blur effect, so that's why you *must* initialize the vibrancy effect with the blur effect of the blurred visual effect view that will be layered behind it. See WWDC 2014 video 221, plus the *UIVisualEffectView.h* header, for lots more information.